# how to solve the empty space in android?

Tags: android, image, android-sqlite

I'm New to android..

I'm using sqlite database. In my database for image i have one row. I'm getting the images correctly in android. But there is no image in database and also in my drawable, I'm getting the empty space in the image view. How to solve this? Any one help me.. There is no error also in my code.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: empty space can you post the two images ?

Comment: post some code what you have done

Comment: post the code, it may help us to find the issue.

Comment: @rajeshcp between question and answer i have image for image question in that image view im getting empty space between que and ans. But i don't have image in my database...

Comment: In database i gave compact after that i delete one image again i gave compact so it allocated one byte. so im getting empty space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update quiz set image = NULL where image ='';     check like this in database..

Answer (score 6):

When you retrieve the image from database, check if it is null.
If it is null then set `ImageView.setVisbility(VIEW.GONE);`
This will remove the space of the ImageView in your layout, or use `View.INVISIBLE` to just make it invisible

BTW, this, probably, should be a comment but I can't comment yet.
If anyone answers properly I'll delete this answer.

Comment: In database i gave compact after that i delete one image again i gave compact so it allocated one byte. so im getting empty space...

Comment: I solved my problem.I wrote query in database like this update quiz set image = NULL where image ='';   Now im not getting empty space...